# Overriding and Overloading Java

Tags: java, methods, overloading, overriding

I have two questions. Im trying to understand Overriding and Overloading

Can we have method overriding without inheriting another class? Why?

Can we have method overloading without inheriting another class? Why?

Comment: Rather than the general questions: What confuses you specifically about the definitions that are available on Wikipedia and other easy to find sites? All you're asking above is for us to regurgitate that which has already been written many times.

Comment: Trying to instruct isn't going to help--this was obviously a homework or interview question and "user" doesn't want to even go do the most basic search for it--in fact notice the rep--this account was probably created just to ask this question.  People who answer questions like this are really only making matters worse.

Comment: Seriously.  Any good textbook or tutorial will answer these questions.  The answers are inherent in the definitions of the terms.  You just need to read them carefully.

Comment: @BillK - actually it wasn't created just for that purpose.  That much is clear if you look at "his" profile.  However, you are correct in your characterization of the problem (IMO).

Comment: Sorry...Geez I wont ask any more questions. You are all wrong I have been looking at different places for try to find an answer but I just didn't fully capture the concept. I think I read about 10 different webpages before  coming here. I'll wait and talk to my professor next time

Answer (score 1):

> Can we have method overriding without inheriting another class? Why?

No. Overriding means that you *override* a method from a super class.

> Can we have method overloading without inheriting another class? Why?

Yes. A overloaded method can occur in the same class but having different signature.

Have you read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)?

Answer (score 0):

No to the first question.
Overriding a method means that you have inherited a parent call and are replacing it's implementation of a method with one that you define in a sub class. You can not override a parent method if there is no parent.

Yes to the second question.
Overloading means that you have multiple methods with the same name but you give them different signatures (parameters) such that they don't clash with each other. This has nothing to do with object oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

**Can we have method overriding without inheriting another class? Why?**

No. As overriding itself means overriding the behaviour(method of inherited class)

**Can we have method overloading without inheriting another class? Why?**

Yes(Overloading means providing method with same name but different signature)

I would suggest you to go thru oops concept (including polymorphism) in detail as its foundation of java language

Here is the what you are looking for

[Overriding and Overloading](http://www.techtamasha.com/method-overriding-and-overloading-in-java/66)

Answer (score 0):

1. Overriding means that you are dealing with two methods: one is in the superclass and the other is in the subclass. So, we can say overriding only exists in the inheritance type of problem.
2. Overloading means that we have two methods having the same names within the same class but these two methods differ in types of arguments they have and the number of arguments they have.

I hope, this is useful. Good day!